# How to make MediaController visible on activity startup

Tags: android, user-interface

here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_video_view);
    VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.player);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    vv.setMediaController(mc);
    vv.setVideoPath("/sdcard/Downloads/test.mp4");
    vv.seekTo(100);
}
```

the mediacontroller doesn't show, but when i click videoview, mediacontroller show like following:

[image]

how to make mediacontroller visible on activity startup

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with change .show position:

```
package ro.rotry;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class TestVideoView extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_video_view);
        VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.player);

        final MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        vv.setMediaController(mc);
        vv.setVideoPath("/sdcard/Downloads/test.mp4");
        vv.seekTo(100);
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mc.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```